# How to change the name of SpatialPolygons in a loop

Tags: r, gis, spatial, r-raster

I wish to create shapefiles grouping countries by regions. The countries polygons come from getData function. I created a dataframe to associate each country to a region. Here is a simple example with Spain (Europe EUR), France (Europe EUR) and Brazil (Latin America LAM).

The final two spatial polygons I wish are:

EUR:
[image]
LAM:[image]

I have written the following loop, but don’t know how to create different polygons for each region i.

```
library(raster)
regions <- data.frame(REGION= c('EUR', 'EUR',  'LAM'), ISO= c('ESP', 'FRA', 'BRA'))

for (i in c('EUR', 'LAM')){ 
    for (j in c('ESP', 'FRA', 'BRA')) { 
    ISO_code <- regions[regions$REGION==i & regions$ISO==j,]$ISO
    if (length(ISO_code)==0) next #as FRA will never be in LAM for example
    else {
      temp <- getData('GADM', country=as.character(ISO_code), level=0)
      if(j==1) regionpoly <- temp
      else regionpoly <- gUnion(regionpoly, temp)
    }
    }
}
```

The current output of this loop is:
[image]

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would merge your `regions` data frame with the data slot of a country-level SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. You can then split the the spatial object into a list according to the regions you defined.

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

regions <- data.frame(REGION = c("EUR", "EUR",  "LAM"), 
                      ISO = c("ESP", "FRA", "BRA"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load data into a list
states <- lapply(regions$ISO, function(x) getData("GADM", country = x, level = 0))

# Combine into a single SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object
states2 <- do.call(bind, states)

# Merge with regions data frame
states2@data <- merge(states2@data, regions, by = "ISO", sort = FALSE)

# Split into list by region
states_split <- split(states2, states2$REGION)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. An issue is that when I plot EUR for instance, the countries shown are BRA and FRA `plot(states_split$EUR)`. Not sure how to fix this...

Comment: Sorry, that was due to `merge()` automatically reordering its output — I'm not used to base R joins . . . It should be fine now.